# Why the C# DataTable.remove() method removes the value passed through parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

The purpose is to move a row into a DataTable to the first position, so once I get the row I remove it and then I insert it into the first position.

```
 DataRow[] dr = DataSet1.Tables[0].Select("field1 = HELLO");

 DataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(dr[0]); // Here dr[0] is removed. Why?
 DataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr[0], 0); // Now a null value is inserted
```

the second line remove both the value into de DataTable and the `dr[0]` passed as parameter so I cannot insert then at the first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because dr[0] is just a reference, you will need to clone it and then remove it.

Comment: Yes but `dr[0]` is taken from anoter dataset `Dataset1`not from which I want to remove from.

Comment: If you dont make a copy its the same object and will lose its value as soon as you remove it. Make a copy, remove the original and insert the new 1.

Comment: I can't see why it's the same object since I take from diferent sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below logic...

```
var row = DataSet2.Tables[0].Select("field1 = HELLO").First();
var oldIndex = DataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf(row);
DataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
DataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
```

this is just logic.. so ignored null checks and exception handling